# How to come back from the pipe file?

Tags: linux, vim, fifo

Using a mkfifo command we can create our pipe file. After that, I just opened that file using a vim editor.

```
  mkfifo pipe_file

  vim pipe_file
```

But i can't come back to my terminal, How can I comeback to terminal?

Answer (score 6):

First of all,
a FIFO is a blocking IO. A process blocks on reading a FIFO, that is, when you issue `vim somefifo`, the vim process waits until another process opens the `somefifo` for writing.

So you can try another process, e.g., issue `echo "foo">somefifo` in a new terminal, then you can do normal operation in your vim process, like `ZQ` to quit.

Comment: For whatever reason, I need two writes to the FIFO to successfully unblock Vim. Or, more accuratedly, two newlines. So if Kent's suggestion does not work, try `echo A>somefifo` and then again `echo A>somefifo`.